# Flutter PopupMenu entries over PdfViewerScaffold

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm currently creating a feature to download different versions of a document. The reason i'm working with a horizontal menu is the fact that nothing is able to show on top of the PdfViewer i'm using.

Is there a way to get the entries over the pdfViewer?
I used [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43859331/horizontal-alignment-of-popupmenuentry) thread to create a horizontal menu, but the items dont fit.

[pdf view with PopupMenuButton](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mO3Au.png)

[Menu open](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Phlhh.png)

the menu:

```
PopupMenuButton<String>(
  icon: const Icon(Icons.arrow_drop_down),
  itemBuilder: (BuildContext context) {
    return [
      PopupMenuWidget(
        child: Row(
          children:
              ['Original', 'Signed', 'Certificate'].map((String choice) {
            return Expanded(
              child: PopupMenuItem<String>(
                value: choice,
                child: Row(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    const Icon(Icons.file_download,
                        color: AppColors.colorDark),
                    Text(choice),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            );
          }).toList(),
        ),
      ),
    ];
  },
  onSelected: (String value) {
    setState(() {
      // download chosen option
    });
  },
);
```

the costum class from the other thread can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43859331/horizontal-alignment-of-popupmenuentry)

Pdf viewer:

```
          PDFViewerScaffold(
              appBar: AppBar(
                leading: IconButton(
                  icon: const Icon(Icons.chevron_left),
                  onPressed: () {
                    popViewer();
                  },
                ),
                centerTitle: true,
                title: Text(widget.document.document.fileName),
                actions: [downloadFunction],
              ),
              path: _pdfPath,
            )
```