# showMenu flutter: want to show items by horizontal

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

i want to create a menu popup horizontal when long press the icon category. i using `showMenu` function in flutter. but it's displayed in vertical

this is my code:

[image: this is my code now]

this is design i want:

[image: this is menu i want]

I also attach my code

```
 GestureDetector(
                    onTapDown: _storePosition,
                    onLongPress: () {
                      final RenderBox overlay = Overlay.of(context)!
                          .context
                          .findRenderObject() as RenderBox;
                      showMenu(
                        context: context,
                        position: RelativeRect.fromRect(
                          controller.tapPosition & const Size(40, 40),
                          Offset.zero & overlay.size,
                        ),
                        items: [
                          PopupMenuItem<String>(
                            value: '1',
                            child: _category(
                                'assets/icons/category_apartment.png'),
                          ),
                          PopupMenuItem<String>(
                            value: '2',
                            child: _category('assets/icons/category_beer.png'),
                          ),
                        ],
                        elevation: 8.0,
                      ).then<void>(
                        (String? itemSelected) async {
                          print('itemSelected $itemSelected');
                        },
                      );
                    },
                    child: RepaintBoundary(
                      key: controller.globalKey,
                      child: Image.asset('assets/icons/icon_category.png',
                          height: 25.0),
                    ),
                  ),
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43859331/horizontal-alignment-of-popupmenuentry

Comment: thanks for your help. i'm implement success

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may achieve this using Overlay

Run the code below and adapt it with your code.

It creates an Overlay then adds it next to the item clicked by using `context.findRenderObject()` to find coordinates. Then the overlay can be removed using `Overlay.remove()`[image]

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

const Color darkBlue = Color.fromARGB(255, 18, 32, 47);

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData.dark().copyWith(
        scaffoldBackgroundColor: darkBlue,
      ),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: ProfilePage(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class ProfilePage extends StatelessWidget {
  const ProfilePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text(
          'Profile Page',
        ),
      ),
      body: Column(
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
        children: [
          Row(
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
            children: [
              const CountryFormField(),
              Text("Som Text"),
              Text("Som Text"),
              
            ],
          ),
          Text("Som Text"),
          Text("Som Text"),
          Text("Som Text"),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class CountryFormField extends StatefulWidget {
  const CountryFormField({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _CountryFormFieldState createState() => _CountryFormFieldState();
}

class _CountryFormFieldState extends State<CountryFormField>
    with TickerProviderStateMixin {
// focus node object to detect gained or loss on textField
  final FocusNode _focusNode = FocusNode();
  OverlayEntry? _overlayEntry;
  GlobalKey globalKey = GlobalKey();
  final LayerLink _layerLink = LayerLink();
  OverlayState? overlayState;
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    overlayState = Overlay.of(context);
    WidgetsBinding.instance!.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
      globalKey;
    });
  }

  OverlayEntry _createOverlay() {
    RenderBox renderBox = context.findRenderObject() as RenderBox;

    var size = renderBox.size;
    Offset position = renderBox.localToGlobal(Offset.zero);
    return OverlayEntry(
        builder: (context) => Positioned(
              top: position.dy + size.height / 2,
              left: size.width,
              child: Material(
                elevation: 5.0,
                child: Row(
                  mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                  children: [
                    InkWell(
                      onTap: () {
                        _overlayEntry?.remove();
                        _overlayEntry = null;
                      },
                      child: Icon(Icons.refresh),
                    ),
                    Icon(Icons.done),
                    Icon(Icons.close),
                    Icon(Icons.search),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ));
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ElevatedButton(
        onPressed: () {
          if (_overlayEntry != null) return;
          _overlayEntry = _createOverlay();

          overlayState!.insert(_overlayEntry!);
        },
        child: const Text('SUBMIT'));
  }
}
```